# What is the meaning of the highlighted sentence given down below?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Roy stopped talking. We sat and stared at the shadows, **oversized and faint off the lattice fence.**

[image]

Comment: the shadows from the lattice fence and the shadows are oversized and faint.

Comment: still doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Imagine a **film noir** effect such as [these](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=film+noir+shadow+effect&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author is saying that 'we' can see shadows from the fence.

It is possible that he is trying to show that it is late in the evening, when shadows get very long, but also faint due to lack of light.

It is also possible (not enough context to be sure) that this is set after sunset, and the shadows are from an artificial light - as a 'point source' they can throw shadows that are larger than the item itself, but again, would be likely to be faint if the scene is generally dark.

Comment: It seems very obvious that they are looking at the shadows being cast by the lattice fence and they appear to be over-sized and faint (just as shadows tend to be)

Comment: @BruceMurray Shadows at mid-day are always very short, and in bright light shadows will be very sharp.

Comment: I know!  What's your point?  Do you think the passage is taking place at mid-day on the Equator?